# Search a website using items gathered items from a list then returning URLS

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
pathName = 'pathName'
export = pd.read_csv(pathName, skiprows = [0], header = None)    
omsList = export.values.T[1].tolist() #Transpose the matrix + get second path
```

So I can get a list of items from a CSV like this an example item would be '11-0128-CH'. What I would want to do is use all these items to run a search on the Lowe's website.
[image]

So I search '11-018-CH' on Lowes and I'm redirected to

https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Voltaire-Kitchen-Faucet-Chrome-1-Handle-Deck-Mount-High-Arc-Residential-Kitchen-Faucet/1002623048

Then run that search and the get the URL that is returned from that search. Is this something that is possible with Beautiful Soup or Selenium if so, then can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: Loop through the omslist and send the keys to  , click it , check if the page is valid and than add to an array. Navigate back to previous page.

Comment: @AMC I'm not sure where to start or how to approach this problem of automating a websearch on a website

Comment: @chrisHG Then you likely need a guide/tutorial, or the documentation. This is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AMC could you link me to a guide or tutorial, I could not find anything that deals with specific webpages, only google searches

Comment: @chrisHG I don't really know of any, sorry. I just followed the Selenium docs.

Comment: @AMC your comment helped out a bunch with researching, I figured out the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 100% overcomplicated this problem, most websites have some search URL they have so for this problem

https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=[something] would do the trick